# Generic routing

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to know if it's possible to make a generic route in Play Framework.

In MVC.Net you can do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",                                             // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                          // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults);
```

With the above route, a lot of urls are covered. So it handles:

```
/customers
/customers/add
/orders/edit/29
etc.
```

When I want to do this in the [Scala Play routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting) I have to declare a route for each url.

My questions is if it's possible to have some sort of generic routing in Play framework?

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't supported in Play!, all urls to an action must be declared manually in route file.

You have to implement it your own using reflection
See [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)